# How to display success or failure message with AJAX

Tags: ajax

I am trying to display a success or failure message after submit with this AJAX code but it's not working. The form submits successfully, but the messages do not appear.

**My code:**

```
 $('#frm-create-vessel').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        $.post(url, data, function (data) { //submit to table
            if(data == true ){             //if the form submits successfully
                $('#createvesselmessages').removeClass('hide').addClass('alert alert-success alert-dismissible').slideDown().show();
                $('#createvesselmessages_content').html('<h4>Vessel Created Successfully</h4>');
                $('#modal').modal('show');
                $("#createvesselmessages").fadeOut(4000);
            } else {                     //if the form fails
                alert('false')
            }
            showVesselInfo(data.vessel_name);
        });

        $(this).trigger('reset');
    })
```

Comment: When you debug, what *does* happen?  Are there any errors on the browser's debugging console?  Is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Is the callback function invoked?  What's in the `data` variable?  What happens in that function?

Comment: can you `console.log(data)` before `if` statement and see what you got

Comment: @Saif When i fill the form correctly, the data saves to the table but I don't get the success message. That's actually my problem right now. When i use console.log(data) i get all the values. I just want the if else statement to work

Comment: I think what I am not getting correctly is the if statement

Comment: what `data == true` is the controller return `bool` value?

Comment: This is the controller

public function createVessel(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            return response(Vessel::create($request->all()));
        }
    }

Comment: try to do this for testing `var test = "true" ` before if statement and then do`if(test == true)` and see it works or not

Comment: "When i use console.log(data) i get all the values". So that implies `data` is an object containing multiple properties / values? In that case, it's unlikely to also consist of simply `true` is it? Which would potentially explain why your if statement isn't working properly. What would you expect the server to return if the request _failed_? Would it even return a 200 OK HTTP code? Often if there's a crash it might return 500, or a validation error might result in a 400. Security issues a 401/403, etc. If that's the case then you need to handle the error response separately anyway.